# Creating a dataset in SAS, what does n+1 do?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to understand a code in SAS because I have to translate it into R. I never worked with SAS before and I don't have access to this software, so it's pretty hard for me to understand and at the moment I'm struggling with the line "n+1".

This is one part of the code I have to translate:

```
data s2;
 infile 'G:\FFT\US\VP4506_101014_235300_FFT_C3-A2.txt' 
   delimiter='",' firstobs=40 TRUNCOVER LRECL=1500
 ;
 input file : $40. subj $ deriv $ stage $ time : $30. incl  hz1-hz50;
 artef=10-incl;
 time=scan(time,2,' ');                     
 n+1;
 starttime=11;  
 if n>(480+10) then delete;
 Kammer=0;
 expo=8;
```

Until the line `n+1` I understand everything i think, but I have no idea what this line does. What is `n`? the number of observations? is there one observation added? 
I see that you need `n` for the following line `if n>(480+10) then delete` but I also do not understand what this line is for.

Hope you can understand me (my english is not that good). Thanks for your help!

Kate

Comment: Do you have access to SAS documentation?  support.sas.com

Comment: It is SAS's increment operator. n+1 is essentially n = n + 1

Comment: N is essentially a row number here and it's saying for some reason, read only the first 490 records. You're likely also dropping some information from the source file. There's a free SAS Programming for R users course if you need to be doing a lot of this, that's probably worth the two days of learning.

Comment: as for the `if n>(480+10) then delete`, the statement could just as well be `if n>(480+10) then STOP` because when the criteria is met no more observations are output (due to `delete`)

Comment: thank you everyone! @Reeza, the SAS Programming for R users course sounds interesting, where do I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that program is reading some type of report and converting it into a dataset that can then be used for analysis.  It is using the variable N that it creates as a way to number the observations. It also testing N so that it will ignore the end of the file.

The variable N is being created using a SUM statement.  The syntax for a SUM statement is

```
variable+expression;
```

It will replace the value of variable with the sum of variable and the value of expression. Note that is uses the SUM() function for this so that missing values of expression are ignored rather than causing variable to become missing.  It will also mark the variable as being retained (not set missing before the next iteration of the data step) and set its initial value to zero.

So the first observation read (line 40 of the text file) will get N set to 1 and then on the second observation N will increase to 2, etc.

Comment: could you also explain what happens with the variables starttime, Kammer & Expo? they have just one value so I ask myself if every observation has the same value on this variables?

Comment: are they assignment statements with the simple syntax variable = expression ?

Comment: `variable=expression;` is an assignment statement.  Yes. If you assign the same constant , without any conditional logic, then that variable will have the same value on every observation.